# List Row Remain selected / highlighted

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

List View's row remains highlighted when coming back from the detail screen, as shown in the screenshot. Tested in Xcode 12 and iOS 14.
List Code:

```
        List(dummyArray) { item in
        NavigationLink(
            destination: DummyDetailDView(),
            label: {
                CustomRow(item: item)
            })
    }
    .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

[image]

**Edit 1:**
I observed that this only happens when my List View is part of any Container View.

Comment: Check if you have multiple NavigationViews or if the SwiftUI view is presented from another UINavigationController.

Comment: @pawello2222 No I do not have multiple navigation views.